# what is the cause of run time error in this code?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I was trying to solve a problem( https://www.codechef.com/LOCMAY17/problems/LOC172) on an online judge. Following is the code for the problem.When i submit the judge gives runtime error().
All the variables have been used acc to constraints.Please help me in finding out what is going wrong?
the code is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
long long int h,w;
while(1)
{
    cin>>h>>w;
    if(h==-1 && w==-1)
        exit(1);
    int n,i,j;
    cin>>n;
    long long int arr[n][4];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i][1]>>arr[i][2]>>arr[i][3];
        arr[i][4]=0;
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if((llabs(arr[j][2]-arr[i][2]))<=arr[j][3])
                arr[i][4]++;
        }
    }
    long long int max=arr[1][4];
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i][4]>max)
            max=arr[i][4];
    }
    cout<<max<<endl;
}
}
```

I am a beginner at this site,thanks in advance.

Comment: Does CodeChef accept dynamic arrays?

Comment: Technically your program is not a valid C++ program, because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: `long long int arr[n][4];` should not compile. `n` is not a constant.

Comment: Also remember that array indexes are *zero* based. So an array of four elements have indexes from `0` to `3` (inclusive).

Comment: for(i=1;i<=n;i++)? Where starts an array index?

Comment: Lastly, perhaps you should try to find [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to help you learn C++, instead of sites like codechef?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude,i tried doing int arr[100][4] for that,but still it is giving run time error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude,i also changed indexes from 1 to 4 to 0 to 3,still not working

Comment: C++ doesn't have implicit int rule (neither has C by the way), hence `main()` is invalid. If your compiler accepts tjis program, throw it away and find a non-broken one.

Comment: @n.m.,I did it int main and return 0,still same runtime error is there.

Comment: I didn't say that it's the reason of your error. I said that your compiler is broken because it accepted this broken code, and that the source that taught you to write `main()` is broken because it taught you to write broken code. If you want to continue using either one, it's up to you.

Comment: Now if you want to see a reason why your program crashes, it's this: `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`. You don't use arrays like that in C++, but I think someone has already pointed that out. In fact you don't use arrays at all but it's a different story.

Answer (score 1):

Is hard to find a run time error on a code that is not compiling...

this is invalid

```
long long int arr[n][4];
```

because you are doing this:

```
int n,i....
```

but **n** must actually be a ***compile-time*** constant, this is just because C++ doesn't allow variable-length arrays

having say that, arrays are 0 base index data containers so this here is causing a UB:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

because you are leaving the element at index 0 intact and writing to a place out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: Not only constant, but a *compile-time* constant. It's not the cause of the runtime error though, that would be the array indexing going out of bounds.

Comment: I changed the memory allocation to static by int arr[10][4],still it is showing run time error.